# Understanding line in the derivation of KL divergence optimising function in Variational Bayes

Tags: bayesian, expected-value, variational

I am following the derivation of Variational Bayes approach in [David Blei's lecture notes](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/variational-inference-i.pdf), particularly equations (13 - 16).

In particular, the line:

$$
= E_q [\ \log_2 q(Z) ]\ - E_q \left[\ \log_2 \dfrac{p(Z, x)}{p(x)} \right]\ 
$$

$$
= E_q [\ \log_2 q(Z) ]\ - E_q [\ \log_2 p(Z, x) ]\ +\log_2 p(x)  
$$

In particular, is it correct the last term goes from $ E_q [\ \log_2 p(x) ]\ $ to $ \log_2 p(x) $ because the expectation w.r.t $q(Z)$ is not relevant for the log probability over $x$?

EDIT:

Just to be explicit in the step I mean. My understanding is Eq 14 goes to Eq 15 by:

$$
= E_q [\ \log_2 q(Z) ]\ - E_q \left[\ \log_2 P(Z|x) \right]\
$$
$$
= E_q [\ \log_2 q(Z) ]\ - E_q \left[\ \log_2 \dfrac{p(Z, x)}{p(x)} \right]\ 
$$
$$
= E_q [\ \log_2 q(Z) ]\ - E_q [\ \log_2 p(Z, x) ]\ + E_q [\ \log_2 p(x) ]\ 
$$
$$
= E_q [\ \log_2 q(Z) ]\ - E_q [\ \log_2 p(Z, x) ]\ +\log_2 p(x)  
$$

With my question on the disappearance of $E_q$ on the last two lines

Comment: Your reference explicitly says otherwise.   In the following line beginning "notice that," it points out that because $p(x)$ does not depend on $Z,$ you can ignore the $\log_2 p(x)$ terms in the minimization problem.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did not appreciate this in terms of taking this expectation. As such, is it not the same as what I said (rather than otherwise): that $q(Z)$ is not relevant for $p(x)$? so $ E_q [\ \log_2 p(x) ]\ $  becomes $\log_2 p(x)$

Comment: Re the edit: the expectation of a constant is that constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In that case one more question if you wouldn't mind enlightening me further as this is something I am quite confused about notation-wise. $p(Z)$ is probability distribution over the random variable $Z$. $p(z)$ is probability at some fixed $z$? $p(Z,x)$ is the marginal distribution of the r.v. $Z$ given some fixed value of $x \in X$? and so $\log p(x)$ is log probability at a fixed $x$ and is thus a constant?

Comment: yes already answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435846/notation-of-random-variables